# Inequality involving AM - GM: $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{1+a_i} \ge \frac{n}{1+{{(a_1.a_2...a_n)}}^{1/n}}$

Tags: inequality

given that
$a_i > 1$, how do I prove that
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{1+a_i} ≥ \frac{n}{1+{{(a_1.a_2...a_n)}}^{1/n}}$$
by applying AM - GM inequality?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to AM/GM inequality,

$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{1+a_i}
\ge \prod_{i=1}^{n} \left( \frac{1}{1+a_i} \right)^{\frac{1}{n}}.
$$

Now let's see the RHS expression.

$$
(1+a_1)(1+a_2) > 1+a_1a_2
\qquad \text{(as $a_i > 0$)}
$$

Similarly,

$$
\prod_{i=1}^{n} (1+a_i) > 1 + P_n \tag{1} $$

and you can also proof that $\prod_{i=1}^{n} (1+a_i) < \frac{1}{1-P_n}$. Since the reciprocal of the expression $\text{(1)}$ can be seen as

$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{1+a_i}
\ge \prod_{i=1}^{n} \left(\frac{1}{1+a_i}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}
> \left(\frac{1}{1+P_n}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}
> \frac{1}{1+P_n^{1/n}} $$

Hope this helps.

Comment: $\LaTeX$ tip: use `\left` and `\right` to get the bracket sizes correct. You may also want to put a pair of brackets on the third line since burger or multiple layer fractions are not well defined

Comment: Taking reciprocal to $\text{(1)}$ reverses the direction of the inequality.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about AM/GM, but you can get it by applying Jensen's
inequality to
$$f(x)=\frac1{1+\exp(x)}$$
which is a convex function for $x>0$. Then
$$\sum_{i=1}^n f(b_i)\ge nf\left(\frac1n\sum_{j=i}^n b_i\right)$$
for $b_i>0$. Set $b_i=\ln a_i$.

Answer (score 0):

Go by the definition of AM-GM.We see-

$$\frac{\frac{1}{1+a_1}+\frac{1}{1+a_2}+...+\frac{1}{1+a_n}}{n}\geq\sqrt[n]\frac{1}{(1+a_1)(1+a_2)...(1+a_n)}$$

$$\implies\frac{1}{1+a_1}+\frac{1}{1+a_2}+...+\frac{1}{1+a_n}\geq\frac{n}{\{(1+a_1)(1+a_2)...(1+a_n)\}^\frac{1}{n}}$$

Now,$(1+a_1)(1+a_2)=1+a_1a_2+a_1+a_2\geq1+a_1a_2$.So,by induction,you can show that $(1+a_1)(1+a_2)...(1+a_n)\geq1+(a_1a_2...a_n)$.

From here it follows that,$$\frac{1}{1+a_1}+\frac{1}{1+a_2}+...\frac{1}{1+a_n}\geq\frac{n}{\{1+(a_1a_2...a_n)\}^\frac1n}\geq\frac{n}{1+(a_1a_2...a_n)^\frac1n}$$

Comment: Are you sure? I think your solution is wrong.

Comment: Why?where is it wrong?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Which part is wrong?

Comment: You forgot $n$ in the second inequality.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Is it ok now?

Comment: No! How you get a left inequality in the last row?